# Send email when you edit a field in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have employee application where users standing can be resigned, active, new and transferred. What i would like to achieve is that when the standing of an employee is changed/edited from active (standing_id = 1) it should be able to send through an email but its not. I have put a email function in the EmployeeController. Below is my code.

```
function _sendNewEmployeeEditMail($id) {
$Employee = $this->Employee->read(null,$id);
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('no-reply@test.com' => 'Testing App'));
$email->to(array('jaahvicky@gmail.com' => 'Name Surname'));
$email->subject('New Employee');
$email->template('employee_email');
$email->viewVars(compact('Employee'));
$email->emailFormat('html');
$edit_email = true;    
$current_status = $this->Employee->field('standing_id');
if($current_status==1) {
$edit_email = false;
if ($email->send()) {
$this->Session->setFlash('Your employee has been submitted.','default',array('class' => 'notification'));
return true;
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash('Your employee has not been submitted.','default',array('class' => 'error'));
return false;
}
}
}
```

and in my edit save function here is how i am trying to send the email

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Employee->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Employee->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid employee'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Employee->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee has been saved'),'default',array('class' => 'notification'));
            $this->_sendNewEmployeeEditMail($this->Employee->getLastInsertID()  );
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.'),'default',array('class' => 'error'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Employee->read(null, $id);
    }
    $standings = $this->Employee->Standing->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('standings'));
```

Comment: You are just preparing the mail in your `_sendNewEmployeeEditMail` function, but you are never calling the `send()` method of the CakeEmail component, so it's to be expected the mail never goes out.

Comment: @Oldskool i have put in the send() method and still not receiving any email. Any idea on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$this->Employee->getLastInsertID()`, which will only be present after *inserting* a new Employee.

Because you're editing an existing Employee, this will always be empty. You should use the $id in stead;

```
$this->_sendNewEmployeeEditMail($id);
```

Comment: Even though this may not solve the problem, this seems to be a bug (insertid). However, have you tried isolating the problem? e.g. sending the email by manually calling the sendNewEmployeeEditMail() with a fixed id? Checked log files?